# Can I uninstall my Steam games but still have the save?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

I realize that there was a similar problem to this that was answered, but i want to be safe by asking this. I'm running extremely low on disk space and I'm thinking of buying games because of the upcoming Summer Sale, so I was wondering if I could just uninstall them, then reinstall them onto an external Storage. Thus I could save a lot of Gb and have an exclusive Storage for my games.

Comment: You can navigate to the save folder, copy out the save files, uninstall the game, reinstall it on the external storage, then move the save files back again.

Answer (score 3):

Some games will keep your save data in a separate folder such as your documents folder on your computer, which means you shouldn't lose the data in those cases when you uninstall.

I also believe the Steam Cloud feature sure work on most titles in terms of keeping your save data.

But as Ben said it's always recommended to manually find the save yourself and copy it just to be safe.

Comment: I am not sure about Documents being safe. Frankly, they should not be, since after uninstalling a game you'd have no choice but to manually delete them.

Comment: Each game will potentially put the save in a different location.  Some are in the userdata folder within your steam installation, some will be in %appdata% folder, some will be in the corresponding "Local" folder (go to %appdata%, up one folder then into local such as `%appdata%\..\local`) and some will be in the same folder as the installed game.  You can google "where is my `insert game name` save steam" and that usually gives you enough information for the location of the save.  In most cases uninstalling a game keeps the save in its place, but don't rely on that..copy/move the save first.